# radio button in while loop

Tags: php, html, mysql

i am coding a page for the attendance of students and in the page all the students name are retrieved dynamically from database using while loop and inside the while loop i have used a radio button.

my problem is the radio button work's correctly but i am unable to insert the value of radio buttons into database.here is my code :

```
include'connection.php';
@$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `std_register` AS p1 ,`sims-register-course` AS p2 WHERE p2.semester=p1.std_semester and p2.department=p1.std_department and p2.id = '".$id."'");
if ($res==FALSE) {
echo die(mysql_error());
                }
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) { ?>

    <input type="hidden" id="dept_0"            name="dept[]"           value="<?php echo $row["department"] ?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="course_name_1"     name="course_name[]"    value="<?php echo $row["course_name"]  ?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="std_semester_2"    name="std_semester[]"   value="<?php echo $row["semester"]  ?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="std_id_3"          name="std_id[]"         value="<?php echo $row["id"]  ?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="std_name_4"        name="std_name[]"       value="<?php echo $row["std_name"]  ?>">
    <tr>
    <td class =info><?php echo $row["std_name"];?></td>
    <td><input type="radio"             name="<?php  echo "status['".$row["std_name"]."']" ?>"  value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="radio"             name="<?php  echo "status['".$row["std_name"]."']" ?>"  value="2"></td>
     </tr>

    <?php   }?>
    </table><br>

    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-3">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Assign" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary"></div></div>
    </form>

    <?php 
    for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $stdid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['std_id'][$i]);
    $dptname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dept'][$i]);
    $courseName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['course_name'][$i]);
    $stdSemester = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['std_semester'][$i]);
    $std_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['std_name'][$i]);
    $present = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status'][$i]);

    $totalClasses = $present;                                            
    $insrt = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `attendence_student` (department_name,courseName,semester,present,absent,total_classes) VALUES('$dptname','$courseName','$stdSemester','$present',0,0)") or die(mysql_error());

        }

    }
```

and is it possible to insert values from this radio buttons to two columns of database?

Comment: You should not use sql as it's deprecated. Look into SQLI or PHP PDO for both foreward compatability and security. What errors are you getting? Is it connecting to the db ok ?

Comment: yes database connects perfectly.

Comment: the error i get here is:
Undefined offset

Comment: try putting "where stdid=`$stdid`" on the end. your query

Comment: did you try the WHERE clause at the end of your SQL ?

Comment: @Billy
where is not working..
and i don't have stdid in database.

Comment: Sorry, it should have been std_id according to Your code above `for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) {if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {$stdid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['std_id'][$i]);` you have the std_id put in a variable but you don't use it in the query, your DB doesn't know which row to update

Comment: no i have not use where clause.
@Billy

Comment: no.
i need to insert.
not update.
@Billy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but try to add 'checked' property in radio input

```
<input type="radio" name="<?php  echo "status[".$row["std_name"]."]" ?>"  value="1" checked></td>
```

***Or***
use *Select* tag instead of radio button

**EDIT**
  use this code to insert in present column or absent column

```
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status'][$i]);
$totalClasses = $value;
if($value == 1) //check if present
{
$sql="INSERT INTO `attendence_student` (department_name,courseName,semester,present,absent,total_classes) VALUES('$dptname','$courseName','$stdSemester','$value',0,0)";
}
else  //if absent
{
$sql="INSERT INTO `attendence_student` (department_name,courseName,semester,present,absent,total_classes) VALUES('$dptname','$courseName','$stdSemester',0,'$value',0)";
}

$insrt = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: ok i will try that..
thank you for greate idea.!
will let you know after i try.

Comment: AFTER removing double quotes it give me syntax error.

Comment: i am sorry bro.. i am new to stackoverflow i wanted you to remove single quote.. "status[".$row["std_name"]."]"

Comment: Hmmm.. can you show me the output of print_r($_POST);

Comment: thank's bro for the nice idea (select tag).
is it possible to insert data into two columns from one select tag?

Comment: i have implement the select tag.now it's inserting data to a single column..(present) but i want to insert into present if student present and insert into abasent column if student absent.
and at the end of semester combine both and bring out the total attendence percentage.
so what i need is.
how to insert from single select into a two column?
and thank you so much :)

Comment: Glad select tag worked. Its very simple what you want... give me few mins i will give you the exact code that you want..

Comment: Hey @hassan .. Check out the Edit.. I hope it helps.. and please shift from mysql to mysqli.

Comment: thank you so much.
i have implement the code..and i am now inserting data to two columns using if statement.
thank you so much for great help.
i will mark your answer correct!
be happy have a nice day/night.